# extracting day from timestamp date column in oracle-sql

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I have a table sample below

```
ENABLED    FILE_NAME            SCHEDULED_DATE
1          TEST_20201101.CSV    01-NOV-20 11.00.00 PM
1          TEST_20201102.CSV    02-NOV-20 11.00.00 PM
1          TEST_20201103.CSV    03-NOV-20 11.00.00 PM
1          TEST_20201104.CSV    04-NOV-20 11.00.00 PM
1          TEST_20201105.CSV    05-NOV-20 11.00.00 PM
1          TEST_20201106.CSV    06-NOV-20 11.00.00 PM
..
..
..data till Nov30.
```

I want to update enabled column to 0 for all days where it is Saturday/Sunday.
Tried using extract() but it returns day number for a date eg: extract on 2020-Nov-27 will return 27

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`to_char()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions180.htm):

```
update t
    set enabled = 1
    where to_char(scheduled_date, 'Dy') in ('Sun', 'Sat');
```

Answer (score 0):

The below query can help you to get the particular day from a time

```
 select to_char(SHCEDULED_DATE,'Day') from date_stack
```

Below is to update

```
update date_stack set enabled='0' where SHCEDULED_DATE in (select SHCEDULED_DATE from date_stack where trim(to_char(SHCEDULED_DATE,'Day'))='Saturday' or trim(to_char(SHCEDULED_DATE,'Day'))='Sunday' )
```

[image]